# hsearch library without NULL terminated data

Tags: c, hashtable

I am using the [hsearch library of glibc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/hsearch.3.html) for my application (C Language, on Fedora 17). I found this webpage http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Hash-Search-Function.html which says that the hsearch function *requires* NULL terminated strings for `data` and `key`. I understand the `key` should be NULL terminated, but I am not able to understand whether "NULL terminated data" is really correct or I am referring to an old (or incorrect webpage) information.

I tried to understand the code [here](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/hsearch_r.c;h=0c7f57cb1091d748066b8a5bb0ec70c07dc345b8;hb=HEAD) and it certainly doesn't show that data has to be NULL terminated.

```
ENTRY he_entry = {NULL, NULL};
ENTRY *result = NULL;
...
he_entry.key = key;
he_entry.data = data;
...
result = hsearch(he_entry, FIND);
<result->data contains my data>
```

I was wondering if any one else has observed any similar behavior or not.

(On a side note, the problem actually is that somehow I am able to get same data (result->data) for multiple keys - and this behavior is sporadic. I have being debugging it without much headway so just verifying other facts which I might have missed while using the library).

Next possible step I am planning is (besides debugging my code) to find if my hsearch library is older that what the above link shows.

Any help or pointer would be really appreciated.

EDIT: I couldn't locate the problem so ended up creating my own hsearch like library using the hash algo avaialble [here](http://svn.haiku-os.org/oldhaiku/haiku/vendor/coreutils/5.0/lib/hash-pjw.c). But still, I would like to know if someone else faced a similar situation or if someone has any pointers which I can use to investigate further.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If data is not null-terminated, how would hsearch know where to stop?

Comment: @n.m. What has search to do with 'data'? Search is on 'key' which _has_ to be NULL terminated. AFAIK There is no need for a generic search library (whatever it may be) to peek into the data.

Comment: I thought the library copies the data. Apparently this is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `glibc` manual is just obsolete.  The header file actually defines `ENTRY` as

```
typedef struct entry
  {
    char *key;
    void *data;
  }
ENTRY;
```

The change from `char*` to `void*` was done [in Feb 2000](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blobdiff;f=misc/search.h;h=0ea91c21506d12e0471c3ac3decae62e8bef8c30;hp=ebc525a7a3abc1b16e0b3ef2372b4913068c582d;hb=8ce9ea0ca67b8eff5f1a708d951d969ac9c0ab2a;hpb=93a19c64c994e85e1c3e87cefa1d68c15e7acb0d).

Moreover, the `data` member is referenced nowhere in [the implementation code](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=misc/hsearch_r.c;hb=HEAD).

Comment: Thank very much. This gives me confidence about my understanding that "NULL terminated data" shouldn't matter.